# How do I add conditional counts as a new column in python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to the forum. So please bear me if the question has been asked. I am trying to realize this type of query with pandas because mySQL is just so slow.

```
update a from table_a a, table_b b
set acct_cnt = count(b.trxn)
where a.acct_id = b.acct_id
and b.trxn_dt between a.date1 and a.date2
```

I did some research but my only conclusion is that it is very hard to implement it with pandas. Can anybody give me a hint on how to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pandas this kind of query is not straight-forward since the code defines the algorithm of the process, while in SQL the code is a 'mathematical-statement' of the action that should be performed, without explicitly mentioning the order of the commands.

Your task can be done with pandas in a following way:

Let's say you have 2 dataframes a and b:

```
import pandas as pd

a = pd.DataFrame([[10,'A','2016-02-01','2016-02-05'],
                  [20,'B','2016-02-01','2016-02-05'],
                  [30,'C','2016-02-01','2016-02-05']],
                 columns=['acct_id','name','date1','date2'])

b = pd.DataFrame([[10,'2016-02-02'],
                  [20,'2016-02-02'],
                  [10,'2016-01-02'],
                  [10,'2016-02-03']],
                 columns=['acct_id','trxn_dt'])
```

First step would be to join and count the values you need.
Join can be done only on equality conditions, so we will apply the second condition (between) in the second line:

```
joined = a.merge(b,on='acct_id')
joined = joined[joined.trxn_dt.between(joined.date1,joined.date2)]
```

Then you do the count (using group by) and update:

```
counts = joined.groupby('acct_id').size()
a['acct_cnt'] = a.acct_id.apply(lambda x: counts.get(x,0))
```

eventually, it sums up to 4 rows of code, but each of them is an independent command.